# Find an object in array in Socket IO and NodeJS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, socket.io

i'm having a list of users using arrays in NodeJS when i make console.log(users) it displays that user_name:48 exists in the array but when searching for it using this code it says nothing found,can anyone help me please?

Here is my code :
Server Side :

```
var users=[]; 

socket.on('user name',function(user_name){
          users.push({id:socket.id,user_name:user_name});
          len=users.length;
          len--;
          //Sending th user Id and List of users
          io.emit('user entrance',users,users[len].id);
          io.emit('userslist',users);
        console.log(users); //it displays id:/#BLABLALBA user_name:48
        });
        //Sending message to Specific user
        /*socket.on('send msg',function(data_server){
          socket.broadcast.to(data_server.id).emit('get msg',{msg:data_server.msg,id:data_server.id,name:data_server.name});
          console.log(data_server.id)
        });*/
        socket.on('check',function(){
          var searchTerm = "48",
        index = "";
    for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
        if (users[i].user_name === searchTerm) {
            index = users[i].id;
            console.log(index);
        }
    else
    {
      index = users[i].id;
    console.log(index);
    }
    }
          });
```

Client Side :

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  socket.emit('check');
});
```

I tried a w3schools example and it worked perfectly but after changing the array nothing worked.

**Problem Solved**
After trying typeof i found that the user_name was an integer so i used parseInt to turn 48 into an integer and it work perfectly

Comment: How did you add the "48" user? Maybe you added it as integer and you search for string?

Comment: I added it using users.push and it displayed perfectly on the browser so what you mean with "integer"?

Comment: On Node I would prefer to use the standard ES6 Array.prototype methods like `find()`or  `findIndex()` when searching objects in an array.

Comment: What I meant is that javascript enables you to enter both strings and integers to the same array, so you might inserted 48(integer) to the array and are searching for "48"(string)

Comment: @Gilad Bison okay let's say it's an integer how can I search for an integer or check if it is an integer or a string to solve the problem

Comment: 1. typeof users[i].user_name will return the type of the object
2. you can use 2 equal signs instead of 3 (== instead of ===) to disregard the type - "48" == 48 - true.

Comment: @Redu can you give me an example please? Because I never used es6

Comment: @Glad Bison Ohhh it's an integer right,I used parseInt("48") to turn it into an integer,thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved** After trying typeof i found that the user_name was an integer so i used parseInt to turn 48 into an integer and it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Jquery grep function is useful for this purpose

```
resultArray= jQuery.grep(yourArray, function( item, i ) {
  return ( item.user_id==XXXX );
});
```

if you sure return one row ,

```
result = resultArray[0];

id = result.id,
name = result.name
```

Comment: It doesn't Work with NodeJS because it needs jQuery